# How to check the next symbol(character) during for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
with open("Base_Of_Cars", 'r') as File:
    for symbol in File[::-1]:
        if symbol == "№"
```

In this code I should return the symbol which is **just after "№"**, furthermore as you can see the **for loop** is acting **reversingly because of [::-1]**, so I need to **find it from the end**.

Comment: why not initialize one variable prev = symbol this will store previous value of symbol and once if is satisfied then print prev ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable `prev_char = symbol` to keep a track of the previous character of `symbol`. Then check if `symbol` is equal to  `№`:

```
with open("Base_Of_Cars", 'r') as File:
    for symbol in File[::-1]:
        if symbol == "№":
            # Do something
            print(prev_char)
        prev_char = symbol
```